# Intellij Idea swing JFormDesigner. How to add extended component in designer?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jform-designer

I need to override some method for JTable. How can I insert extended JTable then in my code? If inserting some code in jformdesigner generated code it is overwritten later. How to be in this situation?
Thanks

Comment: `<soapbox>`Yet another reason to avoid Swing code-generating tools.`</soapbox>`

Comment: If your stuck with it JFormDesigner is not the worst to deal with. I think I have done something like this before, but will need to get my laptop..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add the element as a regular JTable. Then, select it, and find the `class` property. Press the little `...`-button, and IntelliJ should start scanning your project files for candidates (I think it looks for anything that inherits a `Swing`-class.) I remember having some difficulties finding my class when I did this a couple of years ago, as far as I can remember I think it needed a compiled version of the class available. I see now that it scans the classpath of the module, so some maven dependencies plus `target\classes`-folders in my case. So make sure it is on the classpath and that you have built your project, and it should be available.

Comment: Thanks. Initially that property didn't find my class. Build / Rebuild helped afterwards =)